# WiFi won't turn on after rooting, still won't turn on after factory reset

Tags: wi-fi, rooting

After rooting my phone, the WiFi wouldn't turn on. When I say it won't turn on, I mean it won't toggle on at all. I cannot flip the switch to put it in the on position.

I decided that I would just reflash the stock OS to remove the root. WiFi still wouldn't turn on. Then I decided to do a factory reset. It still won't turn on.

I don't care about losing anything, I just want to be able to turn the WiFi on.

Comment: Have you checked the logcat for error messages? Those might shed some light on the issue. If you don't know how to do that, please take a look at our [logging tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info).

Comment: We need you to provide more information. Such as phone, what custom ROM and version, what stock ROM and version, did you wipe the cache and dalvik-cache, what way did you flash the ROMs, and anything else helpful. That way we can provide you with a correct answer.

Comment: If it's a Samsung you can flash a more up to date modem through odin

Answer (score 2):

**There can be two causes:**

1. Hardware failure. Unlikely, but a possibility.
2. **Each device has multiple sub-models, and each sub-model has multiple ROMs**. You need to be sure you're installing the ROM meant for your exact device model, even if you are re-installing a stock ROM. If you do install a ROM not meant for your device, you often face issues like these.

   The solution for this is to first **confirm your exact device model**:

   - Boot into your device's bootloader and look up the device version/model.
   - Open the download page of the ROM you installed
   - Download the version specific to your model
   - Install the ROM the usual way, but be sure to do a full wipe/clean of all partitions first from the recovery.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reflash the stock ROM?

By the way, factory reset only wipes data and cache directories which don't even touch the system directory. Normally, the system directory is read-only, but when you have root privileges, you may change something in the system partition, and that cannot be reversed with a factory reset. The only solution is to use a recovery or something and delete all the partitions, especially the system partition, and flash or install your stock ROM/firmware.

You said you can't toggle at all. That occurs when there isn't any device or any driver is not initialized.